# app using camera on phone keeps crashing

Tags: android, camera, imageview

I've been trying to write basic apps that use the native android camera to take a picture and then display the picture. The apps I write keep crashing when I try to display the picture. I even downloaded a project I found on the internet here http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/androids-camera-intent-makes-taking-pics-a-snap/ but even that crashed too on my phone. I'll post the code here; is there something wrong with my phone and how would I fix it? I'm running Android 4.1.1 on my Galaxy S3

```
package com.authorwjf.camera;


    import java.io.File;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Matrix;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.authorwjf.camera.R;


public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;
private Uri mUri;
private Bitmap mPhoto;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.snap)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.rotate)).setOnClickListener(this);
}

    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(mUri, null);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            try {
                mPhoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mUri);
                ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_holder)).setImageBitmap(mPhoto);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}


    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()== R.id.snap) {
        Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "photo.jpg");
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        mUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        startActivityForResult(i, TAKE_PICTURE);
    } else {
        if (mPhoto!=null) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            mPhoto = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPhoto , 0, 0, mPhoto.getWidth(), mPhoto.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_holder)).setImageBitmap(mPhoto);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: And your logcat says what?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mention the permission to use System camera in android manifest XML?

Comment: I did mention the permission and the app is still crashing